# How to set an SQLAlchemy relationship up to access a field value instead of the related instance

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The following totally incomplete snippet defines a basic SQLAlchemy relationship using declarative syntax...

```
Base = declarative_base()
class Movie(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'movies'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    director = relationship("People", uselist = False)

class People(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'people'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable = false)
```

To access the director name it would be something like:

```
assert isinstance(movie, Movie) # <-- retrieved with query or whatever
director_name = movie.director.name
```

If, for convenience, I always want the `director` relationship to just give me the director's name, rather than a People instance, how do you do this?  eg: it should work just like this:

```
assert isinstance(movie, Movie)
director_name = movie.director  # <-- should get the string directly
```

I'm 99% sure I've done this before but can't find any reference code or documentation on it anymore.  I'm going a bit crazy trying to locate it.  Stack Overflow will be a good/permanent reference location for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The association proxy is used for all kinds of "object reference-> attribute reference" styles of transformation on the Python side.  Docs have been newly updated and rewritten:

http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html

Comment: I've been digging through that exact documentation and thinking it was only for relations with intermediate tables... I'll dig further.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What if you use property?

```
class Movie(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'movies'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    _director = relationship("People", uselist = False)

    @property
    def director_name(self):
        return self._director.name
```